Flutter InkWell onTap is not responding to input
New to flutter and trying to learn about InkWell, but doesn't seem to be working properly as I can't get it to do anything. I have also tried to use the box I'm clicking on to taking me to another page with no luck. Below is snippets of the code. Any help is greatly appreciated. This is also following a training course and I have gone back and reviewed it and googled as much as I could to determine this issue with no luck.
main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:wtpa/screens/categories.dart';

final theme = ThemeData(
  useMaterial3: true,
  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    seedColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 131, 57, 0),
  ),
  textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(),
);

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: theme,
      home: const CategoriesScreen(),
    );
  }
}

categories.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:wtpa/Data/dummy_data.dart';
import 'package:wtpa/screens/meals.dart';
import 'package:wtpa/widgets/category_grid_item.dart';
import 'package:wtpa/models/category.dart';

class CategoriesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoriesScreen({super.key});

  void _selectCategory(BuildContext context, Category category) {
    final filteredMeals = dummyMeals
        .where((meal) => meal.categories.contains(category.id))
        .toList();

    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) => MealsScreen(
          title: category.title,
          meals: filteredMeals,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Pick your category'),
      ),
      body: GridView(
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20,
        ),
        children: [
          for (final category in availableCategories)
            CategoryGridItem(
              category: category,
              onSelectCategory: () {
                _selectCategory(context, category);
              },
            )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

category.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Category {
  const Category({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    this.color = Colors.orange,
  });

  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;
}

category_grid_item.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:wtpa/models/category.dart';

class CategoryGridItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryGridItem({
    super.key,
    required this.category,
    required this.onSelectCategory,
  });

  final Category category;
  final void Function() onSelectCategory;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              category.color.withOpacity(0.55),
              category.color.withOpacity(0.9),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          category.title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I think is because you're not using the onSelectCategory argument in your InkWell widget, like this: onTap: () => onSelectCategory()

I have tried it like that as well as onTap: onSelectCategory and that didn't work either. I should mention that with either of those methods, I can click once after a hot restart but it has to be quick to get to the next screen but then can't click the back button.

Based on that, it seems something related to the build phase or the Navigator. Did you get any errors on the console?

There are no errors in the console.

As others have mentioned, if you want a tap action to be handled by your InkWell, you need to set it to do something.
In your code you have:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},             ///// <---- HERE
      splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              category.color.withOpacity(0.55),
              category.color.withOpacity(0.9),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          category.title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

so you have an empty callback for the onTap method. In order for your tap action to do something when the InkWell is tapped, you need to implement this.
I.E., navigate to somewhere:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const YourOtherScreen())
       },
      splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              category.color.withOpacity(0.55),
              category.color.withOpacity(0.9),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          category.title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

You can see another example in the documentation.

I have tried to use onSelectCategory with no luck. That's what I originally started with.

@BrentYaron - What exactly isn't working? What are you trying to achieve? Did you look at the documentation linked in the answer?

I could not reproduce this issue. In case it helps, here is an adaptation of the counter sample app. Instead of incrementing a counter it adds CategoryGridItems to a grid.
You could paste it into a dartpad and try it out.
// Copyright 2019 the Dart project authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license
// that can be found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Category {
  const Category({
    this.title = '',
    this.color = Colors.blue,
    required this.index,
});
  final Color color;
  final String title;
  final int index;
}

class CategoryGridItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryGridItem({
    super.key,
    required this.category,
    required this.onSelectCategory,
  });

  final Category category;
  final void Function() onSelectCategory;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onSelectCategory,
      splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              category.color.withOpacity(0.55),
              category.color.withOpacity(0.9),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          category.title,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge!.copyWith(
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface,
              ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Inkwell Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MealPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MealPage(this.index, {super.key});
  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Meal $index'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Card(
          child: Text(
            'Meal $index',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Color color = Colors.blue;
  final List<CategoryGridItem> categoryGridItems = [];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'You have pressed add $_counter times.',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
          ),
          SizedBox(
              height: 500,
              child: GridView(
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                ),
                children: [...categoryGridItems],
              )),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: 
        () {
          setState(() {
            _counter++;
            color = color.withGreen(color.green + 10);
            final category = Category(title: 'Category $_counter, $color', color: color, index: _counter);
            categoryGridItems.add(CategoryGridItem(
              category: category,
              onSelectCategory: () => Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => MealPage(category.index),
                  )),
            ));
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Add category',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}



That works so I believe it has to do with the navigation between multiple dart files.

I have amended the sample app. It now includes navigation from each CategoryGridItem to a corresponding meal page.
